# How to check valid AADHAR and PAN number in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, verification

how to check entered aadhar and pan number is valid or not, is there any way ?
if entered incorrect number should enter again.

how to check entered  and pan number is valid or not, is there any way ?
if entered incorrect number should enter again.

Comment: Please check out this website They provide paid api.
https://surepass.io/#contact-form

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex like below

```
extension AadharValidator on String {
  bool isValidAadharNumber() {
    return RegExp(
            r'^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}

extension PanValidator on String {
  bool isValidPanCardNo() {
    return RegExp(
            r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}

extension LicenseValidator on String {
  bool isValidLicenseNo() {
    return RegExp(
            r'^(([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2})( )|([A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}))((19|20)[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{7}$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}
```

And you can to validate

```
var panCheck = "BWRCEA7864R@"
Print("${panCheck.PanValidator()}")
Print("${panCheck.AadharValidator()}")
Print("${panCheck.LicenseValidator()}")
```